# How do I fix the following error in my prolog code for the queen problem

Tags: prolog, n-queens

I can't figure out why my code isn't working. I want the code to give me possible combinations for N queens on a NxN chessboard. A possible combination would be e.g. [2, 4, 1, 3] for a 4x4 chessboard. Each digit represent the colume the queen is being placed and as we go through the list we go row by row until we reach the last one. So "2" would be place in the first row in colume 2, "4" would be placed in the second row in colume 4 and so on.

When I use the function n_queens it gives me

**the follwing error:**

ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

**The code:**

```
initliste(M,N,[M|Ns]) :- M < N, M1 is M+1, initliste(M1,N,Ns).
initliste(N,N,[N]).


safe([]).
safe([Q|Qs]) :-
    \+attack(Q, Qs),
    safe(Qs).

attack(X, [Y|Ys]) :-
    X =\= Y,
    abs(X-Y) =\= L,
    L is length([Y|Ys]),
    attack(X, Ys).
attack(_, []).

n_queens(N, L) :-
    initliste(1,N,Board),
    permutation(Board, L),
    safe(L).
```

Comment: It would help to see *how* you "use the function n_queens" such that you get this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog - Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815952/prolog-arguments-are-not-sufficiently-instantiated)

Comment: Use valid arithmetic expressions - see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arithpreds

Comment: Some *queens* solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221482/hints-to-understand-splendid-program-to-solve-queens

Answer (score 0):

You try to compare `L` (in `abs(X-Y) =\= L`) before binding a value to `L` (as you do in `L is length([Y|Ys])`).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how it would then look like? Would appreciate it

Comment: Bind it before you compare it.