# Prolog: Check that boolean predicate is of a certain form

Tags: prolog

I am in first week of learning Prolog and I want to check that a boolean predicate is of a certain form. Specifically, I want to check that true or false is present in the first level or not at all. For example `or(P, or(Q, true))` is not in this form since at the top level you have or, then P, or at the second, then Q, true at the third level.

I have the idea to count each level and perform recursion on each term(not sure if this is the right word to use), and check if true or false is present when the level is greater than 1.

Using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230594/list-length-in-prolog), I wrote the following to count the levels.

```
checker(Term) :- getLevel(Term, 0).
getLevel(or(T1, T2), L):- getLevel(T1, L+1), getLevel(T2, L+1).
```

How would I combine this with an if statement (if it exists) to check if there is a true and false and return fail if the level > 1? So `or(P, or(Q, true))` would fail.

Comment: You have the right idea, but Prolog is not going to evaluate arithmetic expressions unless you use `is` to force it to, so you'll need to change your body to `L1 is L+1, getLevel(T1, L1), getLevel(T2, L1).` Using `succ/2` instead is even better: `succ(L, L1), ...`

Comment: Do you mean `getLevel(or(T1, T2), L):- L1 is L+1, getLevel(T1, L1), getLevel(T2, L1).` How would I incorporate this in an if statement?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this particular problem actually does not require any real arithmetic involving the level or any real conditional logic. I would handle it like so:

```
concrete_boolean(X) :- atom(X), (X = true ; X = false).

checker(or(P, Q)) :- \+ concrete_boolean(P), \+ concrete_boolean(Q).
```

This fulfills the requirement you stated ("check that true or false are not present in the first level") but this is contradicted by the example you gave ("or(P, or(Q, true)) is not in this form"). Because Prolog predicates succeed or fail rather than "returning", we often replace explicit boolean logic with predicates that appear to only handle the successful (true) case. When the pattern fails to match, the predicate will fail, and this gives us the branching behavior we wanted.

What you probably really are after here is a helper predicate that surfaces terms along with their depth in the tree, which you can then use in some other procedure. For instance, with `getLevel/3`, you could easily write a predicate that tests for explicit booleans only on odd or even levels of the hierarchy.

For this, you seem pretty close, but you are conflating things by having `checker/1` provide the base case to `getLevel/2`. What I think you actually want is something like this:

```
getLevel(Term, Part, Level) :- getLevel1(Term, 0, Part, Level).
getLevel1(Term, L0, Term, L0).
getLevel1(or(Left, _), L0, LeftChild, LN) :- 
   succ(L0, L1), 
   getLevel1(Left, L1, LeftChild, LN).
getLevel1(or(_, Right), L0, RightChild, LN) :- 
   succ(L0, L1), 
   getLevel1(Right, L1, RightChild, LN).
```

I felt pretty good about this testing it with atoms, because it seems to do the right thing:

```
?- getLevel(or(p, or(q, true)), Term, Level).
Term = or(p, or(q, true)),
Level = 0 ;
Term = p,
Level = 1 ;
Term = or(q, true),
Level = 1 ;
Term = q,
Level = 2 ;
Term = true,
Level = 2.
```

However, when you try it with variables, things get a little weird:

```
?- getLevel(or(P,Q), Term, Level).
Term = or(P, Q),
Level = 0 ;
P = Term,
Level = 1 ;
P = or(Term, _2390),
Level = 2 ;
P = or(or(Term, _2396), _2390),
Level = 3 ;
P = or(or(or(Term, _2402), _2396), _2390),
Level = 4 .
```

This happens when an unbound variable is unified with one of our clause's heads. What started out as `P` is unified with `or(Left, _)` rather than just leaving it unbound.

The simplest and best way to resolve this is to decide if you actually want holes in your data structure like this, and if you do, annotate them. As an example:

```
?- getLevel(or(var(P),var(Q)), Term, Level).
Term = or(var(P), var(Q)),
Level = 0 ;
Term = var(P),
Level = 1 ;
Term = var(Q),
Level = 1.
```

Prolog also has some tests you can use, namely `var/1` and `nonvar/1` and `ground/1` but in my experience using them usually introduces subtle problems (often with backwards-correctness or data structures with holes) so I'll just mention it here since I'm pretty sure I wouldn't find a correct solution that helps and handles all the weird cases.

**Edit**: Let's talk about handling variables explicitly.

We can modify what I have in the answer to handle this var/nonvar state:

```
getLevel(Term, Part, Level) :- getLevel1(Term, 0, Part, Level).
getLevel1(Term, L0, Term, L0).
getLevel1(T, L0, LeftChild, LN) :-
    nonvar(T), T = or(Left, _),
    succ(L0, L1), 
    getLevel1(Left, L1, LeftChild, LN).
getLevel1(T, L0, RightChild, LN) :-
    nonvar(T), T = or(_, Right),
    succ(L0, L1), 
    getLevel1(Right, L1, RightChild, LN).
```

Implementing `checker/1` is fairly straightfoward with this:

```
checker(Term) :-
    \+ (getLevel(Term, Boolean, 1), 
        nonvar(Boolean), 
        (Boolean = true ; Boolean = false)).
```

It's tempting to do this instead:

```
checker(Term) :-
    \+ (getLevel(Term, Boolean, 1), 
        (Boolean = true ; Boolean = false)).
```

The problem here is that you'll surface P or Q in `or(P,Q)` and
then bind them to true or false, which will then cause the rest of the
expression to fail. Prolog really doesn't want you to conflate a
domain-specific idea of variable with its internal sense of variable. We can *sort of* get away with it here using `var/1` and `nonvar/1` to protect our unifications and ensure they aren't happening against a totally unbound variable. But I remain anxious about the long-term effects and would regard it as a bit of a code smell if I saw it in someone else's program.

Comment: Thanks for calling out the contradiction with my example. I want to check that true or false is present in the top level or not at all in the tree. I have checker provide the base case to helper because checker has to be a unary predicate.

Comment: How about skipping the "it's getting weird" part of your answer by enforcing sufficient instantiation upfront? Something like `getLevel(Tree, Part, Level) :- ( \+ ground(Tree) -> throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) ; getLevel_aux(Tree, Part, Level) ).`

Comment: @repeat because the question is written in terms of unbound variables, and I didn't feel certain that there is no better way of handling it.