# Prolog evaluation of unknown variables

Tags: prolog, programming-languages

Consider this:

```
list_length([], 0).
list_length([H|T], N) :- list_length(T, N - 1).
```

It doesn't give a compilation error, but it doesn't work.

my thinking is:

suppose i call `list_length([1], N)`

we query `list_length([], N - 1)`

it tells you that `N - 1 = 0`

it finds out N is 1 and returns that value of N.

Instead, with `gprolog`, it tells me `no`.

In particular, it is also surprising it compiles, given something like:

```
?- 1 - 1.
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,(-)/2),top_level/0)
```

Comment: What would be the point in having many different programming languages if they were all the same? You don't get a compilation error because your code is valid. `N-1` does not do arithmetic in Prolog, it's just a term (datastructure) with a variable and a number and a dash. "*it tells you that N - 1 = 0, it finds out N is 1*" - does it? It tells me that `N-1=0` is false, because the they don't unify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List Length in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230594/list-length-in-prolog) (Paulo Moura and garciparedes' answers)

Comment: No @TessellatingHeckler

Answer (score 1):

`-` is not always an arithmetic operator. `N - 1 = 0` will not succeed with `N = 1` because `=` is **not** arithmetic constraint solver.

If you are using gprolog, `N - 1 #= 0` will give you `N = 1`. Your code will work with this:

```
list_length([], N) :- N #= 0.
list_length([H|T], N) :- list_length(T, N - 1).
```

`list_length([], 0)` is equivalent to `list_length([], N) :- N = 0`, so it all comes down to, `=` vs `#=`.

- `=` does unification,
- `#=` does arithmetic constraint solving.

```
| ?- list_length([1, 2, 3], N).
      1    1  Call: list_length([1,2,3],_29) ? 
      2    2  Call: list_length([2,3],_29-1) ? 
      3    3  Call: list_length([3],_29-1-1) ? 
      4    4  Call: list_length([],_29-1-1-1) ? 
      5    5  Call: _29-1-1-1#=0 ? 
      5    5  Exit: 3-1-1-1#=0 ?                  <--------here
      4    4  Exit: list_length([],3-1-1-1) ? 
      3    3  Exit: list_length([3],3-1-1) ? 
      2    2  Exit: list_length([2,3],3-1) ? 
      1    1  Exit: list_length([1,2,3],3) ? 

N = 3

yes
```

You can see in a already linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230594/list-length-in-prolog), there are multiple better ways to do this.