# Infinite loop for user-defined list_length

Tags: prolog, logic, programming-languages

Here is a list length method:

```
list_length([], 0).
list_length([_|T], N) :- list_length(T, TN), N is TN + 1.
```

If I query `list_length(X, 1)` and pass over the first answer, it infinite loops. Here's a trace:

```
| ?- list_length(X, 1).
      1    1  Call: list_length(_26,1) ? 
      2    2  Call: list_length(_58,_97) ? 
      2    2  Exit: list_length([],0) ? 
      3    2  Call: 1 is 0+1 ?
      3    2  Exit: 1 is 0+1 ? 
      1    1  Exit: list_length([_57],1) ? 

X = [_] ? ;
      1    1  Redo: list_length([_57],1) ? 
      2    2  Redo: list_length([],0) ? 
      3    3  Call: list_length(_84,_123) ? 
      3    3  Exit: list_length([],0) ? 
      4    3  Call: _151 is 0+1 ? 
      4    3  Exit: 1 is 0+1 ? 
      2    2  Exit: list_length([_83],1) ? 
      5    2  Call: 1 is 1+1 ? 
      5    2  Fail: 1 is 1+1 ? 
      2    2  Redo: list_length([_83],1) ? 
      3    3  Redo: list_length([],0) ? 
      4    4  Call: list_length(_110,_149) ? 
      4    4  Exit: list_length([],0) ? 
      5    4  Call: _177 is 0+1 ? 
      5    4  Exit: 1 is 0+1 ? 
      3    3  Exit: list_length([_109],1) ? 
      6    3  Call: _206 is 1+1 ? 
      6    3  Exit: 2 is 1+1 ? 
      2    2  Exit: list_length([_83,_109],2) ?
```

I don't quite understand what's happening in the trace, especially after `X = [_] ? ;`.

I do understand why `list_length([],0) :- !` fixes the problem.

I'm in the process of learning Prolog and logic programming so would like to more deeply understand what's going on here and why this infinite loop is happening. I understand the execution model and order at a basic level.

Comment: That method only works decently if the list is closed, i.e. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is_list/1  Count up from 0 instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234136/

Comment: This becomes an infinite loop because X can be an infinitely-long list, and the list is iterated through (by element) until the ending tail of `[]` (an empty list) is found.

Comment: How does X become an infinitely long list? @brebs

Comment: If we provide an uninstantiated variable `X` as the list, when we call the predicate, then that variable `X` can be anything. Each iteration of the code checks for the tail being empty, or not. The code will only **stop** when the tail is empty, otherwise there is the choice to continue into infinity. Note that the linked solution code does not have this problem - an *accumulator* is a more robust and efficient method in general.

Comment: But how does Prolog make it an infinitely long list? @brebs I'm a bit confused how it's "generating" a longer list.

Comment: With each iteration, there is the option to keep growing the list. And that option is taken, because the list is not "closed" (i.e. of a definite length). There is nothing in a "can-be-anything" variable to decide when the end of the list is reached. Prolog is a *declarative* language, it's very different to other types of language.

Comment: The short answer is the behaviour of a predicate upon query depends on the instantiation mode of the given arguments (var vs partial vs ground).  --  After writing some two pages of essentially an introductory article to Programming in Prolog :), and still not being done, let me rather try and offer a link, in the hope that you'll find it useful (together with how it is used in the code), even if just to narrow down your question(s): [Answer Sources :: Code docs](https://github.com/jp-diegidio/Nan.System.Sources-Prolog/blob/master/Code/sources_docs.txt)